# MS Access: Query Expression Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've got an access database to keep track of a number of awards to different people. They split the award by taking a given percentage (Yes, I realize the percents don't add up to 100, I'm just testing it right now). As of right now I have one column dedicated to calculating the first person's split of the prize money. However, I'd like to instead do this with a query instead.

[image: Award Table]

I've created a query to total all of the awards received by a given person, starting with the first column for testing purposes. The query first gathers all the awards in which a given person has a share, then in a separate field multiplies the award by the percentage taken. However, after entering the person's name in the dialogue box, I get this error returned that says my expression isn't typed correctly.

[image: Query Error Message]

I've tried several different things, from changing the formatting of the columns, to editing the expression in the final field where the calculation is done. I can't figure out why this is happening. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can't `Sum` persons. Use `Group By`in that coloumn.

Comment: Well...It really was something obvious.